# How to export an asp:GridView's TemplateField fields to excel in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Does anyone have an example (code or a link) that will allow me to export a gridview template field to excel?  Here is an example of what I mean.  Assume I have the following GridView Declaration:

```
<asp:GridView Id="gvResults" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contact Info">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <b>Name:</b><%# Eval("Name") %><br/>
                <b>Address:</b><%# Eval("Address") %><br/>
                <b>Phone:</b><%# Eval("Phone") %><br/>
                <b>E-mail:</b><%# Eval("Email") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

When I export to excel, I want to export the fields in the template field to columns in the excel file, so it will look similar to this:

Name Address Phone E-mail

==== ======= ==== =====

John 123 Rd  40330 J@j.com

Mark 456 St  22039 M@M.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend to anyone using out of the box asp gridview controls to consider spending some money on a third party package ([DevExpress](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/) is my favorite)

That being said, I have used [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/exportxl_asp2_dc11032006003657AM/exportxl_asp2_dc.aspx) before when I had no other choice

Comment: That doesn't seem to help me in exporting a certain part of the ItemTemplate as a column and another part as the value.

Answer (score 2):

```
    For i = 0 To gvExport.Rows.Count - 1
        For j = rowsLeftTrimed To cellCount - 1

            If gvExport.Rows(i).Cells(j).Text = String.Empty Then
                Dim ctl As DataBoundLiteralControl = _
                  TryCast(gvExport.Rows(i).Cells(j).Controls(0), DataBoundLiteralControl)

                If ctl IsNot Nothing Then
                    sw.Write(Chr(34) & ctl.Text.Trim & Chr(34) & ",")
                End If

            'Else
            '    sw.Write(Chr(34) & gvExport.Rows(i).Cells(j).Text & Chr(34))
            End If
        Next
        sw.WriteLine()
    Next
```